# Beamer add reference to the footer

Tags: beamer, header-footer, presentations

The bottom of the page should looks like this.

[image]

But some page there can be multiple references.

[image]

As you can see the the ref font size and the frame number font size is not the same, that is excellent.

The last reference should align with the frame number, so both bottom part should be on the same line.

Some frame does not have reference. But on each frame keep four "place" for the references. So always keep four "place" free on each frame.

I have absolutely no idea how could I achieve that.

**Code**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usecolortheme{beaver}


%no navigation symbols
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
%no headline
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
%no footline
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
%insert frame numbering
\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{
    \usebeamerfont{footline}
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}
    \hspace{1em}
    \large \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
}
%no frame number on the title frame
\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begingroup
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Outline}
  \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
  \endgroup
}
%first real frame number starts from 1
\let\otp\titlepage
\renewcommand{\titlepage}{\otp\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}}


%black title color
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=black}
%black frame title color
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black}



\author{Author\\[10mm]{\small Supervisor: Supervisor}}
\title{Title}
\institute{Institute}
\date{Date}



\begin{document}

\begingroup
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\frame[plain]{
    %title graphic to the top
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{logopolito}
    \hspace*{1cm}~%
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{logopolito}
    \hspace*{1cm}~%
    \includegraphics[width=2cm]{logopolito}

    \titlepage

}
\endgroup


\begin{frame}{Test 1}

\begin{columns}

\column{0.5\textwidth}
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
\column{0.5\textwidth}
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
\end{columns}

\end{frame}


\begin{frame}{Test 2}

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Test 3}

Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

**Answer**

```
\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{}

\setbeamertemplate{footnote}{%
  \usebeamerfont{footline}
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}
  \setlength{\parskip}{0.5pt}
  \parindent \hspace{-0.9cm}\noindent%
  \raggedright
  \tiny \insertfootnotetext\par%
}
```

Comment: Please don't edit answers into your question. Also `\usebeamerfont{footline}
  \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}` is not necessary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are luckily not using the footline for the framenumbers, you could use `\footnote`s, `\footcite` (from biblatex) or similar tools to add your references.

Here a short example with unnumbered footnotes:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
\usecolortheme{beaver}


%no navigation symbols
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
%no headline
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}
%no footline
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{}
%insert frame numbering
\addtobeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}{
    \usebeamerfont{footline}
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{footline}
    \hspace{1em}
    \large \insertframenumber/\inserttotalframenumber
}
%no frame number on the title frame
\AtBeginSection[]{
  \begingroup
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Outline}
  \tableofcontents[currentsection]
  \end{frame}
  \endgroup
}
%first real frame number starts from 1
\let\otp\titlepage
\renewcommand{\titlepage}{\otp\addtocounter{framenumber}{-1}}


%black title color
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=black}
%black frame title color
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black}



\author{Author\\[10mm]{\small Supervisor: Supervisor}}
\title{Title}
\institute{Institute}
\date{Date}

\renewcommand{\footnoterule}{}

\setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\fontsize{8}{0}\selectfont}

\setbeamertemplate{footnote}{%
  \hspace{-0.8cm}\noindent%
  \raggedright
  \insertfootnotetext\par%
}



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Test 3}

Lorem Ipsum\footnotetext{ref} is simply\footnotetext{ref} dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How could I position them even more to the left. As you can see in my example I put them close to the frame border.

Comment: @pal99 `\setbeamertemplate{footnote}{%
  \hspace{-1cm}\noindent%
  \raggedright
  \insertfootnotetext\par%
}`

Comment: And I would like to change the paragraph spacing to very low, I have tried   `\setlength{\parskip}{1pt}`, but still there is a lot space between them

Comment: @pal99 `\setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\fontsize{8}{0}\selectfont}`

Comment: Look at my question, I have just added, what I have tried useing, but `\setlength{\parskip}{1pt}` is does not working

Comment: The spacing comes from the normal lines, beamer does not use a parskip, so setting it to 1pt would actually increase the distance between paragraphs.